# Instruments Leaks Tools Tips

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, memory-leaks, instruments

I have some memory leak on my iOS app. I've marked a generation, opened a new VC, came back to the previous VC and marked the second generation after the second VC's `deinit` was called.

Instruments clearly shows that I have leaks. However I have trouble understanding what happens. For example, on the images below, a leak appears to happen in the method `initScrollView()` but the `annotations` show `93.5%` on a line that, according to me, cannot leak...

I've search for tutorials but I couldn't find a good one that enlightens me about the last part: Understanding WHAT causes the leaks. Even if I know that requires some research, I'd like to have some tips and TODOS !

Here are my screenshots:

1) stacktrace
[image: stacktrace]

2) Annotations
[image: annotations]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is use the Leaks instrument to find the source of memory leaks. Your screenshots are from the Allocations instrument. All the 93.5% in your example tells you is the attributedTitle allocates 93.5% of the memory the initScrollView() function allocates. It is not telling you the attributedTitle attribute leaks memory. Your approach to using Instruments is correct: switch to the call tree view, invert the call tree, and hide the system libraries. For memory leaks your approach will be more effective if you use the Leaks instrument.

Keep in mind that all the Leaks instrument can tell you is where your code allocates leaked memory. The place where your code allocates leaked memory may not be the source of the leak, but it is a good place to start looking. The source of the leak is going to depend on your code so a tutorial is not going to be able to tell you the source of the leak in your code.

If you are looking for tutorials, [Ray Wenderlich's site](http://raywenderlich.com) has a bunch of Instruments tutorials. I also wrote an article introducing Instruments on my blog, which has several articles on using Instruments

[Getting Started with Instruments](http://meandmark.com/blog/2016/02/getting-started-with-instruments/)